# GPO with SAMBA as DC

Tags: login, samba, domain, replication

I am working on a network of 500 Windows workstations with Linux servers.  SAMBA 4 is in use as the domain controller.

Users can move between workstations, and as a results the contents of their profiles (including MyDocuments) appear to replicate everywhere they login, causing very slow login (up to 20 min)

Can I create and push out Windows Group POlicies to force the contents of My Documents onto a network samba share (folder redirection)?  If so, what tool do I use to create the GPO under Linux?  (Debian)

Is there a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: You might be better asking this on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I thought since it's SAMBA related the Unix forum might be better but I'll give that a shot

Comment: Yes, you might get some advice here. Good luck either way.